# How do "made by" and "made in" differ?

Tags: prepositions, difference

made **by** VS made **in**

Example:

> This film is *made **by*** India.
>
> This film is *made **in*** India.

Answer (score 5):

> This film is made by India.

As it refers to *India*, the whole country, it would (usually) mean that the film was made by the Indian Government, like propaganda...

> This film is made in India.

Normally, this should be what you are trying to say. It means that the location (country) of the film was shot in India.

Comment: Would you like to differentiate between "made by"and "made in"? When to use these things .Where to use?

Comment: @user124234 `made by` refers to the people who made the film.   
Example: **Batman was made by Christopher Nolan**   
On the other hand, `made in` refers to the location   
Example: **Batman was made in USA**   
(USA is the filming location, Nolan is the director or maker)

Answer (score 2):

Who made the film? Indians? Then, it should be...

> The film is made by Indians

The string `made in India` goes more with something being produced/manufactured in India.

> This pen is *made in India.*

However, `made in India` could possibly mean that the shooting was done in India. But then, we have better way to say that...

> This film was *shot in India.*